# Showing line numbers in dired file browser in Emacs

Tags: emacs, line-numbers, spacemacs, dired

I am unable to show line numbers in Emacs when browsing files using Dired.

```
   Dotspacemacs-line-numbers '(:relative nil
     :visual t
     :disabled-for-modes ;; dired-mode
                         doc-view-mode
                         markdown-mode
                         ;; org-mode
                         pdf-view-mode
                         ;; text-mode
     :size-limit-kb 1000)
```

but line numbers are not showing.

any idea how to enable line numbers in Dired?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on minor mode `display-line-numbers-mode`:
`M-x display-line-numbers-mode`. `C-h f` tells you:

> `display-line-numbers-mode` is an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp
> function in `display-line-numbers.el`.
>
> `(display-line-numbers-mode &optional ARG)`
>
> Toggle display of line numbers in the buffer.
>
> This uses `display-line-numbers` internally.
>
> This is a minor mode.  If called interactively, toggle the
> `Display-Line-Numbers mode` mode.  If the prefix argument is positive,
> enable the mode, and if it is zero or negative, disable the mode.
>
> If called from Lisp, toggle the mode if `ARG` is `toggle`.  Enable the
> mode if `ARG` is `nil`, omitted, or is a positive number.  Disable the
> mode if `ARG` is a negative number.
>
> To check whether the minor mode is enabled in the current buffer,
> evaluate `display-line-numbers-mode`.
>
> The mode’s hook is called both when the mode is enabled and when it is
> disabled.
>
> To change the type of line numbers displayed by default,
> customize `display-line-numbers-type`.  To change the type while
> the mode is on, set `display-line-numbers` directly.
>
> Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 26.1.

Comment: Thanks, how to make it permanent using my .spacemacs config file?

Comment: Please pose only one question per post. Pose a separate question, if you want to know how to enable a minor mode in your init file.